# I am trying to optimize the first chunk of code. Why doesn't my approach work? What's the best approach to shorten the code?

Tags: javascript

The code I try to optimize:

```
function classToggle1() {
    document.getElementById("div1").classList.toggle('fa-folder');
    document.getElementById("div1").classList.toggle('fa-folder-open');
}
function classToggle2() {
    document.getElementById("div2").classList.toggle('fa-folder');
    document.getElementById("div2").classList.toggle('fa-folder-open');
}
function classToggle3() {
    document.getElementById("div3").classList.toggle('fa-folder');
    document.getElementById("div3").classList.toggle('fa-folder-open');
}
document.querySelector('#x').addEventListener('click', classToggle1);
document.querySelector('#y').addEventListener('click', classToggle2);
document.querySelector('#z').addEventListener('click', classToggle3);
```

My approach that doesn't work in browsers:

```
function classToggle(x) {
    document.getElementById(x).classList.toggle('fa-folder');
    document.getElementById(x).classList.toggle('fa-folder-open');
}
document.querySelector('#xx').addEventListener('click', classToggle("div1"));
document.querySelector('#yy').addEventListener('click', classToggle("div2"));
document.querySelector('#zz').addEventListener('click', classToggle("div3"));
```

Here I pass in "div1" "div2" and "div3" as arguments. My understanding is that those two code chunks should behave the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

```
document.querySelector('#xx').addEventListener('click', () => classToggle("div1"));
document.querySelector('#yy').addEventListener('click', () => classToggle("div2"));
document.querySelector('#zz').addEventListener('click', () => classToggle("div3"));
```

The point is that, you are passing the output of the classToggle(x) instead of passing the function itself.

Answer (score 1):

In the first example you're passing in the function (`classToggle1`),  and in the second you're invoking the function (which happens to return `undefined`).  You can update the second to enlambda the call.

```
document.querySelector('#xx').addEventListener('click', () => classToggle("div1"));
```

Or

```
document.querySelector('#xx').addEventListener('click', function () { classToggle("div1"); })
```